# zk zAu.send function - org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.MouseEvent cannot be cast to org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.ForwardEvent

Tags: javascript, java, zk

I am integrating jquery and zk project.
My goal is to pass value from js/jquery side to java side but in vain.
Here is the code I reference: [use zAu to send data from client to server](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1hisp5k/3-Use-zAu-send-to-send-data-to-server-from-client#source-1)
However, there exists the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.MouseEvent cannot be cast to org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.ForwardEvent

I have seen some other person saying that we must cast the `mouseevent` to `forwardevent` in order to get a NOT NULL `getData()` value.

At my java side:

```
public class TryHttpLenovo extends SelectorComposer<Component> {


    @Listen("onClick=#btnHttp")
    public void serverReceive(Event e) {    

        ForwardEvent forwardE = (ForwardEvent) e;
        System.out.println("forwardE.getData()"+forwardE.getData());
    }
}
```

In my http.zul:

```
<window apply="foo.TryHttpLenovo" xmlns:w="client">
<button id="btnHttp" w:onClick="sentToServer();">http send</button>
</window>
```

In my testhttp.js:

```
function sentToServer(){
    var wgt=zk.Widget.$('btnHttp');
    zAu.send(new zk.Event(wgt, "serverReceive", {foo: 'my data'}, {toServer:true}));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several trial-and-error, I finally solve this!!!!
The solution is to extend GenericForwardComposer.
I also adjust some other things, but the only important change is to extend GenericForwardComposer instead of SelectorComposer.

The @Listen annotation is not needed in my solution.

in .java

```
public class TryHttpV2 extends GenericForwardComposer { 

    public void onUser2$info(Event event) {
        ForwardEvent forwardE = (ForwardEvent) event;
        System.out.println("forwardE.getOrigin().getData(): " + forwardE.getOrigin().getData());
    }
}
```

in .js

```
function sendToServer(){
    payload = "using generic composer";
    zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$(this), 'onUser2', payload));
}
```

in .zul

```
<?page title="try using generic composer" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<?script src="/js/tryhttp_v2.js" ?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <window id="info" apply="foo.TryHttpV2" xmlns:w="client"> 
        <button id="btnExec" w:onClick="sendToServer();" label="to be tested button" /> 
    </window>
</zk>
```